# docker start container and type command inside has different effect as start container with all command provided

Tags: docker, anaconda

I am in the server's linux system centos7. I am using docker to setup an anaconda environment inside the server.

I can't get access to the mirror outside my country, so I have to set it manually.

however, if I first start the container

```
docker run -it continuumio/anaconda3:2023.09-0
```

and inside container, running

```
conda config --add channels https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/
conda config --add channels https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/
conda config --add channels https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/
conda config --set show_channel_urls yes
```

and then install jupyter:

```
conda install jupyter -y --quiet
```

this will succeed, however if I combine them together as a command to start a new container with jupyter installed,it fails due to the connection, just as what I received if I am not adding the 4 line mirror setting and directly write conda install jupyter -y --quiet.

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3:2023.09-0 /bin/bash -c "\
    conda config --add channels https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/ && \
    conda config --add channels https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/ && \
    conda config --add channels https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/ && \
    conda config --set show_channel_urls yes && \
    conda install jupyter -y --quiet && \
    mkdir -p /opt/notebooks && \
    jupyter notebook \
    --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 \
    --no-browser --allow-root"
```

what happens here?

Comment: (Do you mean to do some of this work in a Dockerfile, so it doesn't need to be repeated every time you recreate the container?)

Comment: @David Maze Hi David,yes, sorry I went to hospital these days so I just notice your message, Do you have any idea?